# Is Fused Location update is recommended to keep in HandlerThread?

Tags: android, thread-safety, fusedlocationproviderapi

I tried to update my location when it changed. For that I am using the Service which contains HandlerThread for the Location updates. But when the app get kills Location update not happening.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the below link

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

If you have bound the service then it runs only as long as another application component is bound to it. I think that is what is happening. Please post code if you need further help.

And HandlerThread for the Location updates is not needed. You will get callbacks on location changed. In case you are running any server call from that you can use volley or other libraries.